# Dictionary of Array not going to sort, type getting changed after sort function

Tags: ios, sorting, swift3

I have a situation where I need to show an index table in my project. So I am creating a dynamic array for section header titles and for index also. I have created the array, but am unable to sort this array. I have 1 object like this:

```
struct StorageData {
    var id: String?
    var version: Int?
    var downloadDate: Date?
    var legId: String?
    var packageId: String?
}
```

and I am getting an array of this from the server. So I just created two arrays.

```
var tableViewSource =  [Character : [StorageData]]()
var tableViewHeaders = [Character]()
```

and trying to fill these array by this statement:

```
  func getTableData(words: [StorageData]) {
    tableViewSource = createTableData(wordList: words).source
    tableViewHeaders = createTableData(wordList: words).firstSymbols
}

    func createTableData(wordList: [StorageData]) -> (firstSymbols: [Character], source: [Character : [StorageData]]) {

    // Build Character Set
    var firstSymbols = Set<Character>()

    func getFirstSymbol(word: String) -> Character {
        return word[word.startIndex]
    }

    wordList.forEach {_ = firstSymbols.insert(getFirstSymbol(word: $0.name!)) }

    // Build tableSourse array
    var tableViewSource = [Character : [StorageData]]()
    let sortedSymbols = firstSymbols.sorted(by: {$0 < $1})

    for symbol in sortedSymbols {

        var words = [StoragePersonal]()

        for word in wordList {
            let data = word.name
            if symbol == getFirstSymbol(word: data!) {
                words.append(word)
            }
        }
        tableViewSource[symbol] = words.sorted(by: {$0.name! < $1.name!})
    }

    return (sortedSymbols, tableViewSource)
}
```

but the data in `tableViewSource` are coming unsorted.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to separate data into sections.

I confuse about data type `StoragePersonal`, it's a child of `StorageData`, isn't it.
And i don't see `name` property in `StorageData` structure.

I think you should change:

```
func getTableData(words: [StorageData]) {
    tableViewSource = createTableData(wordList: words).source
    tableViewHeaders = createTableData(wordList: words).firstSymbols
}
```

to:

```
func getTableData(words: [StorageData]) {
    let result = createTableData(wordList: words)
    tableViewSource = result.source
    tableViewHeaders = result.firstSymbols
}
```

I created a new function to separate data for you:

```
func createTableData(wordList: [StorageData]) -> (firstSymbols: [Character], source: [Character : [StorageData]])
{
    var tableViewSource = [Character : [StorageData]]()
    var firstSymbols = [Character]()

    // first, sort wordList

    let sortedWordList = wordList.sorted {
        if let name1 = $0.name {
            if let name2 = $1.name {
                let compareResult = name1.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(name2)
                if compareResult == ComparisonResult.orderedSame || compareResult == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }

        return false
    }

    // second, separate words into section by the first character

    var previousCharacter = Character("A")
    var previousWords = [StorageData]()
    var otherWords = [StorageData]()

    for word in sortedWordList {
        if let name = word.name {
            let upperCaseName = name.uppercased()
            if let firstCharacter = upperCaseName.characters.first {
                if (firstCharacter < Character("A")) || (firstCharacter > Character("Z")) {
                    // other word (numbers, special characters, ...)
                    otherWords.append(word)
                } else if firstCharacter == previousCharacter {
                    previousWords.append(word)
                } else {
                    // save a section
                    if previousWords.count > 0 {
                        tableViewSource[previousCharacter] = previousWords
                        firstSymbols.append(previousCharacter)
                    }

                    // start new section
                    previousCharacter = firstCharacter
                    previousWords.removeAll()
                    previousWords.append(word)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // save the last normal section

    if previousWords.count > 0 {
        tableViewSource[previousCharacter] = previousWords
        firstSymbols.append(previousCharacter)
    }

    // save the other section

    tableViewSource["#"] = otherWords
    firstSymbols.append("#")

    return (firstSymbols, tableViewSource)
}
```